# How to know the number of results of a Table-Group?

Tags: birt

There is a `Table` in a report , then I inserted a `Group` within it. Then I added a footer row within the Table. I want to hide this row if the `Group` has just 1 row result. So how to know the number of results of the `Group` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select the table -> binding tab -> Add aggregation

Select "count" as function, select any field as expression and set "aggregate on" to the group. Then use this new binding in visibility expression of the footer row.

[image]

Comment: This is the right approach. However, at least BIRT 4.3 has a known bug where COUNT on an empty expression does not work as expected. So you should choose any non-null expression row["SomeNotNullableColumn"]. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=438257

Comment: in fact it is Aggregate on table ( not on group ) !